Find vaadin checkbox in vaadin-grid using testbench
I need to find a checkbox (vaadin-checkbox) which is inside the vaadin-grid-cell-content (part of vaadin-grid), since I can't rely on the ids I need to find another solution. My idea was to get the checkbox by the component next to the checkbox, with the span = "Text". Since I'm new to testbench and selenium, I need your help. Maybe there is a much simpler solution.

Greez and thanks in advance

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.
